# How can I get an Article object form a Stream<List<Future<Article>>>

Tags: dart, flutter

In my app I have a stream of list of Article Ids `Stream<List<int>> articlesIdsStream()` and from that  I want to generate a stream of the corresponding articles( that I need to fetch from web first using the_article() function).

I have tried the following code to generate the stream of articles:

```
  Stream<List<Future<Article>>> articlesStream() {
    Stream<List<Future<Article>>> result =
    articlesIdsStream().map<List<Future<Article>>>((list) {
      return list.map((id)  async {
        return   await _article(id: id); // http get 
      }).toList();
    }).where((stories) => stories != null);
    return result;
  }
```

but the then, how can I easily get a `Stream<List<Article>>` from `Stream<List<Future<Article>>`?

Comment: why dont you simply want a stream like: `Stream<Article>` (or maybe `Stream<List<Article>>`)?

Comment: @pskink Yes I want a Stream<List<Article>>, just reworded the question